# How to convert Drupal 6 user data to WordPress 3?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, drupal

I have used some of the tutorials out there to convert a `Drupal 6` site over to `WordPress`. My problem is that I am not finding any tutorials with the lines I can use in my `MySQL` to convert the users table in `Drupal 6` over to the `wp_users` table in `WordPress 3+`. As I said... everything else has converted perfectly, but this is the only thing left.

Any insight on this?

Comment: I think even if you would find a right way to migrate them, you will still have problem with users passwords because Drupal encrypts passwords and I think it's different from Wordpress.

Comment: Can you show the structure of `wp_users` table?

Comment: Both Drupal and WordPress do MD5 encryption:

Comment: @VladStratulat http://pastebin.com/SWkj6jwj -  I have posted the SQL structure at pastebin because there were too many characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through several tutorials and the room34 site helped. However, once the entire site was converted, the custom permalink was not honored and the postname using the slug had to be used. I have written up the tutorial and process in which I have completely converted Drupal to WordPress that worked. [How to Convert Drupal To WordPress](http://blondish.net/how-to-convert-drupal-to-wordpress/). I have given credits to the blog owner who aided in my issue, my findings throughout the conversion, and of course, the code. I appreciate everyone who answered, but none of it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's help.

```
// Query from Drupal DB all users
SELECT uid, name, pass, mail, created
FROM users
WHERE uid > 0

// Cycle throught all users and insert each one of them into Wordpress DB
foreach ($users as $user)
  "INSERT INTO wp_users SET
  ID = $user->uid,
  user_login = $user->name,
  user_pass = $user->pass,
  user_nicename = $user->name,
  user_email = $user->mail,
  user_url = '',
  user_registered = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user->created),
  user_activation_key = '',
  user_status = 0, // not sure about that
  display_name = $user->name"
}
```

Comment: I got a syntax error when putting this through.

Comment: When you do what? Are you just copy/paste my example? If so, you shouldn't, it's just an example of where you have to go to get your users.

Comment: That is what I did... so that is why.

Comment: I did more digging and this link to the full migration, I think may have the answer. It was strange as the link was not working the other day when I was researching.

Comment: I have done digging and solved this one my own with a tutorial write up.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a blog post documenting my Drupal to WordPress conversion process: [Drupal to WordPress migration explained](http://anothercoffee.net/drupal-to-wordpress-migration-explained/).

It covers how you can migrate both post authors and comment authors. My queries are similar to Nile Flores' since we've used the same source, Scott Anderson's blog post. However, I've also added some modifications over time that have helped with my own site migrations. The explanation is a little long-winded since I discuss a specific example so just pasting the SQL here might not work for you.

I've put it on [GitHub](https://github.com/anothercoffee/drupal-to-wordpress) in case anyone wants to easily clone everything or submit improvements.